# How to remove deferred attribute of SQLAlchemy entity from memory?

Tags: python, memory, sqlalchemy, deferred

For example we have a table that stores `LONGBLOB` objects:

```
class MyEntity(_base):
    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    metadata = Column('META', String(512), nullable=False)
    bigData = deferred(Column('BIG_DATA', LONGBLOB, nullable=False))
```

Column with `LONGBLOB` marked as deferred, i.e. it is loaded only on access to this attribute of particular object.

I need to query list of objects from the database and iterate over collection:

```
entities = dbSession.query(MyEntity).all()
for entity in entities:
    ...
    entity.bigData  # load BLOB from the database and do smth with data
    ...
```

In this loop all BLOBs will be loaded from database and memory will be exhausted. I need a way to clean memory at the end of each cycle. Expunge object from session and remove from memory entirely is not handy...

How to clean up particular attribute of the object (`LONGBLOB`) but do not remove object from the session?

Comment: Have you tried `entity.bigData = None`

Answer (score 1):

Don't load `bigData` into the object. The deferred loading is already doing a query per iteration, so you can do that yourself without associating it with the MyEntity instance:

```
entities = dbSession.query(MyEntity).all()
for entity in entities:
    bigData = session.query(MyEntity.bigData).filter_by(id=entity.id).scalar()
```

`bigData` should be cleaned up as long as no references to it are kept around.

Comment: I am not going to award this answer the bounty - this is quite an obvious workaround and I don't think anyone asking this question would not fall back to this if they had not found the answer. I expect a better informed answer like "not possible because... ", "you need to change private state of the model like...", or "here is a utility function you could not find..."

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski That's fine, but I think the question you want the answer to isn't this one. The question asked for a way to clean up a loaded column. It acknowledged that expunging the entire object was not an ideal solution. It didn't say "I know I can load the column separately, but is there a way to unload a column from an object instead?". The fact that it is deferred is beside the point, since any column can be deferred at load time.